# Why temporary and temporal have totally different meanings?

Tags: word-meaning

temporary means a short period of time,

temporal means relating to worldly as opposed to spiritual affairs.

Why they looked so alike but mean totally different? Is there any connection between them?

Comment: Did you check for other definitions of *temporal*? You should reference definitions (with dictionary links) for both words, then ask your question. Dictionary look-up questions are OT.

Comment: There are many words that look similar but mean different things in English because English borrows from many different languages. These two words aren't as unrelated as you might think. The spiritual realm is eternal and the earthly realm is bound by time. Temporary means fleeting, or not long lasting, like earthly things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions of etymology are listed as off-topic in the [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Why words have different meanings, spellings, pronunciations, etc. is often a matter of where they originated from.

Comment: In this case the meanings are actually related, as Shrodingdong explains. But lots of words sound similar but have totally different meanings. "Books" has nothing to do with "boots" or "cooks", "Tyre" has nothing to do with "tire", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporal means relating to time.

The other meaning loosely comes from this meaning. Worldy affairs, or "the here and now" as opposed spiritual or non tangible things. That which physicaly exists at this moment in time.

It really is not that different a meaning considering that we often refer to existence as "Time and Space".